# Will Aliens attack logistic and construction robots?

Tags: factorio

I know the aliens will always attack combat robots, but I was wondering if they would attack logistic and construction ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep! This is the biggest problem involving aliens in [Seablock mod](https://mods.factorio.com/mod/SeaBlock) since the aliens are all immobile there.  If you have your construction bots building land too close to an enemy base, they'll get killed.